# During OpenBSD installation, what is "DNS domain name" for?

Tags: unix, installation, openbsd, bsd, server-setup

During the installation of OpenBSD 6.1, right after setting up network interfaces, the installer prompts me:
`DNS domain name? (e.g. 'bar.com') [my.domain]`

I am not sure what this setting is for, I left it at default `my.domain` and besides showing up on my prompt, I did not notice anything not working as intended.

Is this option just for proper labeling of the system environment, if not, what is it for?
Should it just be set to the future domain address? What if the system holds multiple domains?

Comment: I know its late, but I had the same question when setting up a home network. Looks like there is a `home.arpa` option available [just for this situation.](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-homenet-dot-07.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wants to know the domain name of the system, so that it can pair that with the hostname to come up with the system's full-qualified domain name (FQDN). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).

I'm guessing this is an installation for your home, where you don't have a default DNS domain, per se. As such, this should probably be asked on Super User rather than Server Fault.

The impact this will have is that software that looks for the FQDN will find it, e.g., mail server software.. It will also impact the domain that gets appended to a lookup. For example, if you type "ping systemxyz" it will actually try `ping systemxyz.my.domain` based on what you entered. Running `man resolv.conf` will also help you understand some of the DNS resolution things that go on behind the scenes of your operating system.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the domain name of a hosted system would be the Standard Name Server of the hosting provider? This is actually not a home installation :)

Comment: It's whatever you want to make up. Give [this article](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/choose-internal-top-level-domain-name) a read.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the explanation and provided links.